# Map Function not working with useEffect inside React-Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, map-function

I want to direct User Profile when a username is clicked. When click the username, get the data of users data is taken and define to userProfile with setUserProfile. After that, get the data of user posts. Then direct to the `/users/${userName}`. Everything works correctly until coming to the Map function inside `UserPost.js` but the inside of the `userPosts.map()` function is not rendered.

After Click the username the API calls start using the username:

```js
useEffect(() => {
         async function fetchProfileAPI() {
        if (userName == undefined) {
            return null;
        }
        const urlUserbyName = `http://localhost:5000/users/${userName}`;
        const result = await axios(urlUserbyName);
        setUserProfile(result.data);
    }
    fetchProfileAPI();
    }, [userName]);
    
useEffect( () => {
        async function fetchUserPostsAPI() {
            if (userProfile == undefined) {
                return null;
            }
            const postsOfUser = userProfile.createdPost;
            const postArray = [];
            postsOfUser.map(async (postId) => {
                const urlPostbyId = `http://localhost:5000/posts/${postId}`;
                const result = await axios(urlPostbyId);
                postArray.push(result.data);
            })
            console.log(postArray);
            setUserPosts(postArray);
        }
        fetchUserPostsAPI();
    },[userProfile]);
    
    // History.Push in useEffect
    useEffect(() => {
        if(userProfile == undefined) {
            console.log("Nullmuş ya la");
            return null;
        }
        console.log("Null değilmiş ya la");
        history.push(`/users/${userProfile.username}`);
    },[userPosts]);
```

App.js React Router Part

```js
const App = () => {
    const { postId, userName } = useContext(MemoryContext);
return (
        <>
            <Router>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path={`/users/${userName}`} exact>
                        <Header/>
                        <Profile/>
                        <UserPosts/>
                    </Route>
                    <Route path={`/posts/${postId}`} exact>
                        <Header />
                        <SinglePost/>
                    </Route>
                    <Route path="/posts" exact>
                        <Header />
                        <PostsList />
                        <AddPost />
                    </Route>
                    <Route path="/" exact>
                        <Header />
                        <PostsList />
                        <AddPost />
                    </Route>
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        </>
    )
}
```

UserPost.js
Everything is fine until here.

```js
const UserPost = () => {
    const { userPosts } = useContext(MemoryContext);
    console.log(userPosts); // This line is printed to console and shows the api call is working correctly
    return (
        <Container>
            <Row>
                {console.log("UserPosts Rendered...")} {/*This line is printed to console*/}
                {userPosts.map((post, key) => {
                    return (
                        <Col key={key} xs={10} md={6} lg={4} className="offset-1 offset-md-0 py-5 px-3">
                            {console.log("UsersPost.map working") /*This line is not printed to console*/}
                        </Col>
                    )
                })}
            </Row>
        </Container>
    )
}
```

Comment: `console.log(userPosts)` what this line is printing? can you share that data?

Comment: @PeterSmith is print the user posts data from coming the API call: `(2) [{…}, {…}]
0: {_id: "607ef4521129bd1b38556e7c", tags: Array(3), likes: Array(0), comments: Array(0), createdAt: "2021-04-20T15:20:54.897Z", …}
1: {_id: "607ef49f1129bd1b38556e7d", tags: Array(3), likes: Array(0), comments: Array(0), createdAt: "2021-04-20T15:20:54.897Z", …}
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)`